# Removing chalkmark sounds from recordings

Tags: audio

I have been recording lectures, but unfortunately these contain a lot of chalk sounds. Is there any way of removing these?

**Related**

- [List item](https://superuser.com/questions/24/remove-noise-from-a-recording) - Removing noise from a recording - this seems to be removing background noise ect which I don't think covers chalk sounds

Comment: Any chance of getting a sample to play with? We might be able to give you a more accurate solution...

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I've decided to just tolerate the sounds until the end of semester and try to play with all these stuff during the holidays

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Programs like Audacity let you create a "noise profile" which is then used to remove noise on the recording. If you can find a few seconds where the only sound is the chalk-board noise, then you can try that.

IME, noise reduction works better in multiple passes than trying to catch it all in one pass.

Answer (score 3):

I know it won't help what you've already recorded, but I think the real solution here is to think about where and how you position and configure the mic.

That said, +1 for Audacity to clean up the existing recordings.

Answer (score 3):

The most annoying part of the chalk is probably the higher frequencies (squeaking), so a simple EQ pass might be able to make the recording more tolerable. Audacity has a few [plugins](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/nyquistplugins) that do EQ. A bit of trial and error and you should be able to quiet the highest frequencies while leaving the voice audible.

Answer (score 2):

You could always use a sound-editing program like [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) (free, open source) and clip them out.

I'm not sure what to do if the chalk noises happened while the instructor was talking, though.